Unable to launch main python script from pyinstaller bundle using launcher script
I'm encountering difficulties with launching a Python script (Ex.py) from a PyInstaller bundle using a launcher script (launcher.py). The launcher script is intended to locate Ex.py within the PyInstaller bundle and execute it. However, despite various attempts, I'm unable to get it to work as expected.
Here's the current setup and the issues I'm facing:
Setup:

launcher.py: This script is responsible for launching Ex.py from a PyInstaller bundle. It determines the base path of the bundle and constructs the path to Ex.py.
Ex.py: This is the main Python script that I want to execute from the PyInstaller bundle.
PyInstaller: I'm using PyInstaller to bundle the Python scripts into an executable.

Issue:
When running the launcher script (launcher.py) after bundling with PyInstaller, I'm getting the following error:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Username\\Ex.py'


I've verified that Ex.py exists in the expected directory within the PyInstaller bundle.
I've tried using sys._MEIPASS to determine the base path, but it didn't resolve the issue.
I've also attempted to construct the path to Ex.py using sys.argv[0], but it didn't work either.

I'm looking for any guidance on how to properly locate and execute Ex.py from the PyInstaller bundle using the launcher script. Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.
Here's the current version of the launcher script (launcher.py):
import subprocess
import sys
import os

def launch_script():
    try:
        # Determine the directory of the executed script or executable
        base_path = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

        # Construct the path to the main script
        main_script = os.path.join(base_path, 'Ex.py')

        # Launch the main script
        subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, main_script], cwd=base_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error launching script:", e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    launch_script()


If you have any insights or suggestions at all, please share them. Or if you require any additional details, let me know. Thank you in advance for your help!

There are a few issues with your setup.  #1 pyinstaller does not bundle a python interpreter with the exeecutable so your program wouldn't work on a computer that didn't have python installed.  2. after compiling with pyinstaller sys.executable  points to the exe file and this is what you should actually be using to find the Ex.py file if it's next to the executable.  If you are using onefile mode and its bundled with the source then you should use __file__
